# Feature Request for adding number of dupe hammers earned near to the badges

Tags: feature-request, dupehammer

Today i gonna suggest a feature request of adding a dupe hammer symbol next to the badges only for the persons who earned that.

[image]

[image]

I think the above picture will explain you clearly. This would differentiate the users who earned and who are not earned dupe hammer.

Comment: The top bar is only visible to yourself; did you mean in the *user card* instead?

Comment: Nah. Just look at [your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1835379/cerbrus?tab=badges&sort=class). It's not like they're handing out Mjolnir like pens at a random exhibition. The number rarely changes.

Comment: yep in user card also..

Comment: then reduce a gold badge from the badges list. Why we mingle the hammer with badge? It would be nice if we have a hammer symbol instead of golde badge.

Comment: The hammer is a "side-effect" of earning a gold tag badge. It makes no sense to remove it from the gold badge count.
You're really going to have to do a better job coming up with a compelling reason why this is a great idea.

Answer (score 13):

## I disagree.

Just look at [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1835379/cerbrus?tab=badges&sort=class) if you forget how many you have. It's not like they're handing out Mjölnir like pens at a random exhibition. The number rarely changes.
Also, having earned a Mjölnir shows in your gold badge count already. The privilege is a responsibility, not something to "show off".

Basically, I don't see the point in this suggestion.